# Como posso fazer esse layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Como posso fazer esse layout?
Em cima é a image, em baixo é uma caixa de testo.
No meio está o problema, são 3 botões e 1 progressbar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Alguma dúvida em especifico?

Comment: Renan, minha dúvida e como posicionar os imagebutton e progressbar do mesmo jeito da imagem acima.

Comment: Mobile, bem vindo ao SOPT. Do jeito que está a pergunta, parece que você quer que alguém faça o layout pra você. A indagação do colega sobre sua "dúvida em específico" é justamente: qual é a dificuldade exata que você teve ao tentar construir o seu layout? Edite a pergunta pra incluir indicações de como você está planejando fazer e até mesmo um screenshot do layout que vc já conseguiu até agora.

Comment: @Luiz Vieira, obrigado pelas boas vindas, sobre minha dúvida é como posicionar os 3 botões e 1 progressbar, que é essa caixa do meio que mandei no print. Até agora só consegui colocar Imagem no Topo e TextView no rodapé, falta o meio.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de um [*LinearLayout*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) ou outro qualquer, além de se poder colocar elementos como **TextView, *ImageView* etc, também se pode incluir outros tipos de layout.

Tendo isto em mente deve começar por dividir o seu layout em layouts intermédios.

Como a distribuição dos elementos que compõem o layout é vertical comece por utilizar um *LinearLayout* com o atributo `android:orientation="vertical"`
Dentro dele coloque a *ImageView* e o *TextView*.

Olhe agora para a parte central e pense nela como um layout separado, suponha que o que queria fazer era essa parte só.

A primeira coisa que notará é que a distribuição dos elementos é horizontal.

Comece com um *LinearLayout* com o atributo `android:orientation="horizontal"`
Dentro dele coloque o botão *play*.

Continuando a nossa análise vemos que a distribuição do *ProgressBar* e dos outros dois botões é vertical.
Abra mais um *LinearLayout* com o atributo `android:orientation="vertical"` e inclua o *ProgressBar*.

Faltam apenas os dois últimos botões.
Nesta altura julgo que você já descobriu como fazer, certo?
Como sua distribuição é horizontal abra mais um *LinearLayout* com o atributo `android:orientation="Horizontal"` e inclua os dois botões.

Feche todos os *LinearLayout* com o atributo `</LinearLayout>`

Inclua todo este conjunto entre a *ImageView* e o *TextView* do primeiro *LinearLayout*.

Optei por fazer a parte central utilizando *LinearLayout* mas o mesmo podia ser feito recorrendo a um [*RelativeLayout*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Os passos enumerados servem apenas para construir o esqueleto do layout. Será necessário recorrer aos atributos de alinhamento, margens e peso para posicionar melhor os elementos.